# Regular expressions in C# for extracting parts

Tags: c#, regex

I have this text:
`" </SYM field/NN name=/IN ""/"" object/NN ""/"" >/SYM Categories/NNS :/: Cars/NNS ,/, About/RB Model/NNP :/: "`

I would like to extract values such as 
`Categories/NNS :/: Cars/NNS ,/, About/RB`

where the pattern is
 `WORD + /NNS + :/: ANYTHING` until you reach the same pattern

I tried:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/NNS :/: ([A-Za-z0-9\-/s]+)",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

and the answer I got back was:
`Categories`

instead of

`Categories/NNS :/: Cars/NNS ,/, About/RB`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the bits of the regex you want as result inside parenthesis.

To obtain what you're looking for, you need to replace your regexp by (not tested, moreover I don't know C# regex specifics but the below should be OK):

```
"((?:[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/NNS :/: (?:[A-Za-z0-9\-/s]+))"
```

The main parenthesis mean that you'll get the entire string as result.
The opening parenthesis followed by ?: mean that you don't want that part in the result.

If you would not put the ?:, it would result in a tuple with your entire string, then the string matching the first sub-regex, then the string matching the second sub-regex.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use match.Value?  Everything you put in parenthesis represents a group, but it looks like you want the whole thing.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/NNS :/: ([A-Za-z0-9\-/s]+)",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```